# Electron-builder with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, electron-builder

**tl,dr:**

**Here's what I got:**

- Electron
- React
- Webpack
- electron-builder
- electron-edge
- node-fibers
- some static assets (.png, .svg etc.)

**Here's what I want:**

- A crossplatform autoupdating installer for the software

**The long version and the problems:**

I can get Electron, React, Electron Edge, node-fibers, webpack and the static assets to run perfectly when I start the webpackserver in dev mode.

However, how can I integrate this into electron-builder?

I'm new to this whole build process and I just took this boilerplate to get started:
[Github of the boilerplate](https://github.com/pbarbiero/basic-electron-react-boilerplate)

To me, the dev debug process seems to go like this:

- Have webpack create a bundle.js and an index.html out of my src folder
- Start a webpackserver with hot mode that serves these files

However, how should I tell electron-builder where to get the different files from? There is no package.json nor node_modules/ inside dist/ and node-fibers isn't getting bundled as well (because webpack seems to fck with __dirname or smth, so I excluded it).

Whenever I launch the generated .exe file (that's not the installer, just an exe file that's supposed to launch the program), a message appears that main.js can't be found in the app.asar file. I tried extracting it, but it fails before it gets to extract the whole package. Main.js is never needed anyway though, because that was the whole point of having webpack transpile it or am I missing something here?

I have searched all over the internet for hours now, but I don't get all the concepts ..

Could anyone here explain what's wrong with my setup and what I can do to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

If you don't want to use boilerplate for react app, consider to use https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack (but boilerplate is strongly recommended).

Comment: I didn't use that one in the first place because it seemed to have loads of stuff that I didn't need. Now I gave it a try, but couldn't even get it to work via the normal commands as explained in the readme.md ... I mean it can't be that hard to just have webpack build a package and have electron-builder to make it an installer afterwards, can it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this boilerplate:

https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate

I couldn't get HMR to work and had to fix some es6 stuff, but at least it's doing its job.